# Dropbox won't start anymore

Tags: dropbox

Since a while, 2 weeks, Dropbox does not startup anymore on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with GNOME shell.

When I run `dropbox start -i` in the console I get the following output.

```
  Starting Dropbox...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1387, in <module>
    ret = main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1376, in main
    result = commands[argv[i]](argv[i+1:])
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1247, in start
    if not start_dropbox():
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 731, in start_dropbox
    stderr=sys.stderr, stdout=f, close_fds=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I already removed Dropbox and reinstalled it. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to reinstall dropbox.

First open a terminal and type the following to remove dropbox:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge remove nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Now type the next commands in sequence to install dropbox.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

[Source](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-dropbox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

Comment: This worked for me apart from apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
That command just hung.  Doing the purge, update and install of Dropbox seemed sufficient.

Comment: Sorry but this did not work for me. Firstly I installed `dropbox` and not `nautilus-dropbox`.

I got the following error `W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E

W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Then try this to install it: `cd ~ && wget -O - "http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -` and to run type this: `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

Comment: `/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` :(

Comment: 1) delete the `.dropbox-dist` folder from your home.
2) open a terminal and type: `dropbox start`
3) then type `dropbox start -i` to link your account

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar error, and this worked:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

After running those commands in the terminal, let the dropbox downloader run and install. It should work immediately after it finishes.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This one worked for me too on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Worked for me, Linux Mint 17.1 (October 2016 today)

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04!

Comment: Just worked on 20.04

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem and found [this fix](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/fix-dropbox-fails-to-start-with.html)

Basically, I fixed the error by reinstalling dropbox distribution with the following terminal commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

Comment: not sure if it has since been updated, but I am `4.2.5-1-ARCH`, and it was located at `$HOME/.dropbox-dist` as @morhook suggested below (http://askubuntu.com/a/416981/307798)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks very much for your answer.
Ubuntu desktop - 14.04 LTS 64 Bit

Comment: For some reason I had the directory under both `/var/lib/dropbox/` and `$HOME`. There was an older version in the former.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but none of this worked. But I found there was a running dropbox process. Even when I asked the status it showed as stopped and it didn't work at all.

My solution was to kill the dropbox process, remove the .dropbox-dist directory and run it again.

First find the dropbox process:

```
$ ps ax | grep dropbox
5490 ?        SNsl   0:01 /home/frankie/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86-2.10.52/dropbox
$ kill -TERM 5490
```

Then remove the dist dir and start it again

```
$ rm .dropbox/dropbox.pid
$ dropbox start -i
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix it (luckily everything was already synced) was by doing ... (**Don't do this is you haven't backed things up or the files are not synced**):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge dropbox` # (for me this was actually `sudo pacman -Rncs dropbox` because I am on arch ... basically, you just need to remove it)

```
find / -name "\*ropbox\*" 2>/dev/null
```

Remove everything associated with the dropbox (including `$HOME/.dropbox-dist`, `$HOME/Dropbox` (will wipe your data obviously, so back it up into a temp. directory or something!!), etc).

No clue why this stopped working, but doing `rm -rf $HOME/.dropbox-dist` unfortunately didn't work for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and then follow the [official instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx):

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &
```