# Have to run dropbox with `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`, why not just dropbox?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, dropbox

I've had nemo file manager with the dropbox extension but after the problem of nemo 2.0 that couldn't render the desktop properly, I removed both of them, and installed nautilus.

Now, I am trying to install dropbox with nautilus, when running `sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox` I am getting this:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  nautilus-dropbox :
>   Depends: dropbox E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

I followed the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251170/dropbox-wont-start-anymore) but I am getting the above error.
After that, I ran this `cd ~ && wget -O - "http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -` as mentioned in the comments of the reply and successfuly ran dropbox daemon with this `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`.

I know that to run dropbox from now on, I will create a new entry at the startup applications with this command `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`.

But my question is, why can't I install it normally and run it with `dropbox start` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package manager (`apt`) failed to install `nautilus-dropbox` because it depend on package `dropbox`, the main software, but didn't find it in the package list. Note that  `nautilus-dropbox` is just a nautilus extension. Usually 3rd party softwares are not included into software sources of an OS due to security reason. In that case we need to manually add it to software sources. PPA are commenly used for this. After successfully updating the sources we can install software without problem using the following command.  `sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox`.  AFAIK there is no PPA for it. They have an online installer package which can be downloadable From [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx). After completing the installation you can use the earlier command to install nautilus-dropbox.
In your case dropbox is not installed to the system. It's a  kind of copying, as we use a portable software. So the system is unaware of the program. If you want to launch it with a single command run the following command.
    sudo ln -s /home/$USER/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd  /usr/bin/dropboxd

Answer (score 0):

Why `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and not `dropbox` to start the daemon? One reason might be that the word dropbox is/was a relatively common name for for the service their company provides. A more specific reason would be that `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` is where it was installed for your local user.

The directions followed are actually those provided by Dropbox, as the [headless installation](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) method, except their last step was left out:

> Download this [Python script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) to control Dropbox from the command line. For easy 
>   access, put a symlink to the script anywhere in your PATH.

With their script, and a little setup as below, you can now use `dropbox start` for manual control, or even `dropbox autostart` to not have to worry about it.

*I keep `~/.local/bin` on my PATH for local installations (those for only my user).*

**Example Setup**

In `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Then run:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
wget -O ~/.local/bin/dropbox.py "https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py"
chmod ug+x ~/.local/bin/dropbox.py
ln -s -T ~/.local/bin/dropbox.py ~/.local/bin/dropbox
```

**Example Use**

> [user@example Dropbox]$ dropbox
>
> Dropbox command-line interface
>
> commands:
>
> Note: use `dropbox help <command>` to view usage for a specific command.
>
> ```
> status       get current status of the dropboxd
> throttle     set bandwidth limits for Dropbox
> help         provide help
> puburl       get public url of a file in your dropbox's public folder
> stop         stop dropboxd
> running      return whether dropbox is running
> start        start dropboxd
> filestatus   get current sync status of one or more files
> ls           list directory contents with current sync status
> autostart    automatically start dropbox at login
> exclude      ignores/excludes a directory from syncing
> lansync      enables or disables LAN sync
> sharelink    get a shared link for a file in your dropbox
> proxy        set proxy settings for Dropbox
> ```

Comment: I found I also needed to run ```chmod 700 ~/.local/bin/dropbox.py``` or I got a permission denied error.

Comment: @RJ, thanks for the reminder. I added a permissions step to the answer.