# Dropbox could not start

Tags: permissions, dropbox

I have problems starting Dropbox, My Dropbox folder path is set to a different internal hard drive from my Ubuntu 16.04 installation drive.

I get the following error message:

[image: Error message from dropbox]

Uninstalling and reinstalling did nothing.
Running chmod 777 did nothing

Comment: Please don't 777 your Dropbox directory >_<

Comment: See this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251170/dropbox-wont-start-anymore)

Comment: What are the contents of `/tmp/dropbox_error92i9bU.txt`?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/mark/mystuff/Dropbox/.dropbox.cache/prefetch_cache'. But i cannot acces the folder.

Comment: And I know not to 777 my dropbox but desperate times call for desperate measures

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing:

Delete Dropbox:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus-dropbox
```

Manually delete the dropboxfolder:

```
sudo rm -r Dropbox
```

Install dropbox again. and it stated syncing

Comment: This seemed to work for me. The only thing I can think of that I did wrong the first time was potentially not restarting Nautilus when prompted.