# Dropbox won't install on Ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: dropbox

I downloaded Dropbox from the official site and then installed it via Ubuntu's software installer. A message advised me to restart my session, so I logged out and in. No Dropbox.

So I chose Dropbox by searching it and the clicking via Activities. The message about installing Dropbox and then about restarting Nautilus appeared. I made my choices, but no Dropbox.

From command line, I chose `dopbox running` - no Dropbox.
`dropbox start` gives the following message:

```
Starting Dropbox...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1535, in <module>
    ret = main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1524, in main
    result = commands[argv[i]](argv[i+1:])
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1395, in start
    if not start_dropbox():
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 732, in start_dropbox
    stderr=sys.stderr, stdout=f, close_fds=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I've tried this over and over with exactly the same result.
Anybody know how to install Dropbox?

Comment: "Exec format error" leads me to believe you have a 32-bit system and have installed 64-bit `dropbox` or vice versa.

Comment: No, I definitely have a 64-bit OS. But after I posted I tried to compile from source - first, I didn't have any compiler, but afgter having gotten that, I compiled... and got the same as above. But could I have downloaded 32-bit Dropbox by mistake? Seems strange, but I will look into that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please add the results of `file /usr/bin/dropbox;uname -a` to your question.

Comment: Here's that output:
/usr/bin/dropbox: Python script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines

Comment: Solved: I found this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/251170/dropbox-wont-start-anymore?rq=1

and uninstalled dropbox and nautilus-dropbox, then executed rm -rf $HOME/.dropbox-dist

then installed nautilus-dropbox from command line

After a second i got the pop-up message sying I should start Dropbox. I did that from command line:
dropbox start -i

and THEN Dropbox started.